# How to prevent the crontab job execution, when it is already running

Tags: scheduled-tasks, cron

I want to schedule a job to run every 5 minutes. but the question is that
Is there a way (like creating a crontab) to prevent a job from running, when the previous job has not been completed?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `shell script` to start the job only when the job is **not already running**. Configure the shell script in crontab every 5 minutes. this will ensure that the execution happens only when there is no instance of the job running already. This is how i have done for my cron jobs

Note : make use of `ps -ef | grep` commands in your shell script to identify if there is a process already running